# React Native migration - Fastlane build fail for iOS "Archive failed" only on CircleCI

Tags: android, ios, react-native, circleci, fastlane

Working on migrating a mobile app from React Native 0.59.0 to 0.60.5 and to support Android X. The updated app works fine on both iOS and Android and the CircleCI build for Android is working fine.

The CircleCI build for iOS using Fastlane fails on CircleCI during the archive. Has anyone else seen and solved this before?

When running `bundle exec fastlane ios build_release` locally it works fine.

```
Environment (on CircleCI):
Xcode version: 10.2.1
Fastlane version: 2.130.0
Gym SDK: iphoneos12.2

+----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                              Summary for gym 2.130.0                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| scheme                                             | MyApp                                                        |
| export_method                                      | app-store                                                    |
| export_options.provisioningProfiles.com.myapp.app  | match AppStore com.myapp.app                                 |
| workspace                                          | ./MyApp.xcworkspace                                          |
| destination                                        | generic/platform=iOS                                         |
| output_name                                        | MyApp                                                        |
| build_path                                         | /Users/distiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2019-09-06 |
| clean                                              | false                                                        |
| output_directory                                   | .                                                            |
| silent                                             | false                                                        |
| skip_package_ipa                                   | false                                                        |
| result_bundle                                      | false                                                        |
| buildlog_path                                      | ~/Library/Logs/gym                                           |
| skip_profile_detection                             | false                                                        |
| xcode_path                                         | /Applications/Xcode-10.2.1.app                               |
+----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+

Output:
▸ Touching MyApp.app
▸ Signing /Users/distiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-crgfinutbidjbqcbnlrwjwautwhq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app
▸ Touching MyApp.app.dSYM
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[06:24:02]: Exit status: 65
[06:24:02]: 
[06:24:02]: Maybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode
[06:24:02]: Found multiple versions of Xcode in '/Applications/'
[06:24:02]: Make sure you selected the right version for your project
[06:24:02]: This build process was executed using '/Applications/Xcode-10.2.1.app'
[06:24:02]: If you want to update your Xcode path, either
[06:24:02]: 
[06:24:02]: - Specify the Xcode version in your Fastfile
[06:24:02]: ▸ xcversion(version: "8.1") # Selects Xcode 8.1.0
[06:24:02]: 
[06:24:02]: - Specify an absolute path to your Xcode installation in your Fastfile
[06:24:02]: ▸ xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode8.app"
[06:24:02]: 
[06:24:02]: - Manually update the path using
[06:24:02]: ▸ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
[06:24:02]: 

+---------------+--------------------------------+
|               Build environment                |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode-10.2.1.app |
| gym_version   | 2.130.0                        |
| export_method | app-store                      |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS12.2.sdk               |
+---------------+--------------------------------+

[06:24:02]: ▸ Touch /Users/distiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-crgfinutbidjbqcbnlrwjwautwhq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.app.dSYM
[06:24:02]: ▸     cd /Users/distiller/mobile-app/ios
[06:24:02]: ▸     export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-10.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-10.2.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/distiller/.gem/ruby/2.4.6/bin:/Users/distiller/.rubies/ruby-2.4.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/bin:/Users/distiller/.rubies/ruby-2.4.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
[06:24:02]: ▸     /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/distiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-crgfinutbidjbqcbnlrwjwautwhq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.app.dSYM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not suggest to set Xcode version in Fastfile because it will change all the time. Maybe you have different Xcode version locally and on the CI machine.

We used to set this at the top of `Fastfile`:

```
xcode_select '/Applications/Xcode.app'
```

Make sure Xcode is in the Application folder with name `Xcode`, it should work then...

Comment: I like this approach more!

Comment: Maybe just missing the command line tools, run: `xcode-select --install` Or try to reinstall Xcode...

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the error log - you are using wrong xcode version, so fastline cant select right one;

to define version of xcode you should add in the fastline config file

```
xcversion(version: "10.2")
```